# scraping a dynamic and inconsistent dom site

Tags: html, dom, xpath

topic 2 is trending thread so it returned an extra markup span, that broke my query. How to solve this kind of problem? if I do //span at the end then the others three are out.

```
    <li>
    topic 1
    </li>

    <li>
    <span style="color:red">topic 2</span>
    </li>

    <li>
    topic 3
    </li>

"poll"
    <li>
    topic 4
    </li>
```

Comment: `span` tag is not closed - is this how the html really looks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `descendant-or-self`:

```
//li/descendant-or-self::text()
```

Demo (using [`xmllint`](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html)):

```
$ xmllint index.html --xpath '//li/descendant-or-self::text()'
topic 1
topic 2
topic 3
topic 4
```

where `index.html` contains:

```
<ul>
    <li>
    topic 1
    </li>

    <li>
    <span style="color:red">topic 2</span>
    </li>

    <li>
    topic 3
    </li>

    <li>
    topic 4
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it work! but can it be more complex? I found the markup of the forum suck.. like if the post is poll, there will have "poll"<li>topic name</li>

Comment: @user3522725 the xpath should handle it too, if I'm correctly understanding what are you saying.

Comment: @user3522725 yup, it is not a problem. The xpath I've provided would still work.

Comment: @user3522725 yup, the example you've provided is working for me. Probably something else on the page prevents it from working as intended. Is there a link or can you provide the full relevant html part? Thanks.